# Validator.js return invalid on random gmail addresses

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, mern

I am creating a mern application and am using validator.js to do some basic email format validation.

Everything is working correctly however some random gmail addresses are returning as invalid emails

example: *test@gmail.com* returns invalid while *testtest@gmail.com* registers completely fine.

I have also tried *1@1.com* to make sure its not a length thing

Here is my validation

```
// Check to make sure email is formatted correctly
    if (!Validator.isEmail(data.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Invalid Email'
    }
```

Here is my mongoose model

```
email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
```

Has anybody experienced something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validator.js module has implemented special validations for the domain "gmail.com" and "googlemail.com". As per the gmail, minimum length of the username should be 6 and maximum allowed can be 30. The same validations are incorporated in Validator.js module.

That is the reason, it is failing for you if the length of the username is less than '6' for gmail and its not failing if you are using domain other than gmail. One more thing, minimum length doesn't include dot.

So,

```
1. test1@gmail.com --> fails.
2. test12@gmail.com --> success
3. test.1@gmail.com  --> fails
4. test.12@gmail.com -- success
5. ab@mydomain.com --> success
```

Hope this clarified.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use RegularValidationExpressionValidator

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator_Email" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" ControlToValidate="TB_Email" ErrorMessage="*Email is invalid" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

for CustomValidaor that is using JS function you can use this function:

```
function ValidateEmail(source, args)
{
    if(!(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(args.Value)))
    { args.IsValid = false; }
}
```

this is the CustomValidaor in the front code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox_Email" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateEmail"></asp:CustomValidaor>
```

Comment: I am using javascript on my server not ASP i have made my own regex to test that works but i am wanting to know if anyone has had issues with validator.js. Thanks for your input though